# 'Samba' no longer working with Ubuntu 16.04 & Windows 10

Tags: 16.04, networking, samba, windows-10

I know that the question has been asked and answered before but none of the solutions could currently fix my problem.

I have two office computers. One running Windows 10 (because I have to) and another one with Ubuntu 16.04 (because I want to). Both computers run the latest version of each OS. My goal is as simple as what sharing a couple of folders and my printer should have been.

After a clean Ubuntu LTS 16.04 installation, the OS installed 'samba' (on its own) as soon as I tried to share a folder and I was able to access both the printer and that folder from Windows 10 and that's all I needed. Everyone was happy. Then a few days ago, I tried to transfer a couple of files (as I used to do almost every day) and the two computers could no longer see each other.

I tried everything I could find online to fix it (meaning: mostly outdated tips about firewall exceptions & possible smb.conf tweaks that no longer apply) without success. Has anyone faced any similar issues lately? Any links to anything (if possible not outdated) that could possibly work?

Comment: Did you setup your samba user ( different to your normal user you login with). Easiest way s to install system-config-samba, setup your users and your shares. Further you can also install the samba plugin for your file manager, eg caja-samba so you have a sharing option in your right click context menu.

Comment: Apparently creating a new user account (different to my own) and adding that as a samba user (as you rightfully pointed out) did the trick. ("Linux for human beings", they said... Yet coming through all this just for setting up a local network makes no sense at all).

I should also point out that restarting samba wasn't enough for the shared directories to show up on Windows 10. A full (Ubuntu) system restart was required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995742/samba-no-longer-working-with-ubuntu-16-04-windows-10?noredirect=1#comment1607856_995742).

Creating a new samba user solved the problem.

Comment: You havnt created a new user account, you have only created a samba user. A samba user can only connect to samba shares, cannot actually login to the system. You can give the samba user your same username and password, thats what I do.

Comment: No, actually I created a new user profile (with no system password that I don't log into) and used that one as 'Unix Username'.

Comment: That isnt needed, you only need to set up samba users. Anyway, you have found a solution. If you want other people to connect to shares moving forward, just add samba users.